# Jquery text hide and show when onkeyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to use jquery text show and hide when onkeyup.

but it doesn't work

this is my code.

this is my jquery

```
Auth.joinCheck = function(mode){

var param;
var password1 = $("#userpasswordPre").val();
var password2 = $("#userpasswordCon").val();

//check id

if(mode == 1){
    param =$("#username").val();
    if(param.length < 2){
        $("#joinNav div.msgRow").show();
        $("#joinNav button.btnJoin").prop("disabled",true);
    }
    else{
        $("#joinNav div.msgRow").hide();
        $("#joinNav button.btnJoin").prop("disabled",false);
    }
    return false;
}
else if(mode == 2){
    if(password1.length < 4){
        $("#joinNav div.msgRow1").show();
        $("#joinNav button.btnJoin").prop("disabled",true);
    }else{
        $("#joinNav div.msgRow1").hide();
        $("#joinNav button.btnJoin").prop("disabled",false);
    }
    return false;
}else if(mode == 3){
    if(password1 != password2){
        $("#joinNav div.msgRow2").show();
        $("#joinNav button.btnJoin").prop("disabled",true);
    }else{
        $("#joinNav div.msgRow1").hide();
        $("#joinNav button.btnJoin").prop("disabled",false);
    }

    return false;


}

}
```

this is my HTML code

```
        <div class="form-group joinName">
            <span>ID :</span><input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" onkeyup="Auth.joinCheck(1);" required />
        </div>
        <div class="msgRow">Id must be more than 4 letter</div>
```

and My css about `msgRow:none`;

`text.show()` does work but type Id more than 4 letter,

`text.hide()` doesn't work...

Comment: there is something wrong css -> msgRow display:none;

Comment: you can use the edit function to make changes to your question. also,

Answer (score 1):

Check this fiddle.
I made some changes on the code.
https://jsfiddle.net/mkd68r8f/

```
 document.getElementById("username").addEventListener("keyup", function () {
     Auth.joinCheck(1)
});
```